# Reading XML short notation value with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xmlnode

How do I get the value `1` with PHP and SimpleXML out of the following xml file?

**data.xml**

```
<users>
 <user name="test">
  <option name="enabled">1</option>
  <option name="setting">on</option>
 </user>
</users>
```

**test.php**

```
$file = 'data.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach ($xml->users->user->option as $option) {
 echo $option['name'];
}
```

**Output**

> enabledsetting

How do I output the value?

Comment: Take a look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: where's the php you've tried?

Comment: I added the php that is false!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the result:

**test.php**

```
$file = 'data.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach ($user->option as $option) {
 if ((string) $option['name'] == 'enabled') {
  echo $option;
 }
}
```

Is there a solution to get it without "if" or "switch"?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution without `if` or `switch` is using XPath :

```
$xml = new simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//option[@name="enabled"]') as $option) {
    echo $option;
}
```

Above XPath expression means, find all `<option>` nodes having attribute `name` value equals `enabled`.